# Арифметический оператор (сложение) в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

**Можно ли при 301 редиректе в .htaccess применять оператор сложения?**

Т.е. создать формулу редиректа, которая будет перенаправлять ссылки:

site.ru/folder/7/
на 
site.ru/?post_type=product&p=707

site.ru/folder/8/
на 
site.ru/?post_type=product&p=708

.........

.........

site.ru/folder/8000/
на 
site.ru/?post_type=product&p=8700

и т д.

Т.е. чтобы 8000 редиректов не прописывать а задать формулой

Comment: Вам нужно менять логику приложения, а не htaccess

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет нельзя в .htaccess применять оператор сложения